# in c# is there a way for ProcessCmdKey when application is minimzed?

Tags: c#, .net

this code only work if application is showed

```
      protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
      {

          if ((keyData != Keys.Z))
              return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

          //NombreMetodo();
          MessageBox.Show("Ctrl is pressed2!");

          return true;
      }
```

But I want to this works if application is minimized

Comment: Have you considered using [global key hooks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-keyboard-hook-in-c/)

Comment: If the application is minimized, then it doesn't have focus, and ut doesn't receive input UI events. What are you trying to achieve, and why?